# jQuery - Hide delete icon unless sibling elements are added/present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which allows users to dynamically add or remove rows by clicking `+` or `-`, respectively. But, users shouldn't be able to delete the very first row of any day, so there should only be a `-` if they've added at least one row to the day in question.

Currently, I handle this by just not responding to `remove()` when the `-` icon is clicked and there are only 7 rows (the absolute minimum).

Here's the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/b92sh7yn/

Specifically, the workaround in question is here:

```
 function remove() {
   if (cloneIndex > 7) {
     $(this).closest(".actions").prev(".time-interval").remove();
     cloneIndex--;
   }
   console.log(cloneIndex);
 }
```

This works, but the behavior I want is to not show the `-` icon for the first row of each day and only have it shown when new/sibling rows are added for each day and hidden again if those new/sibling rows are removed.

I tried showing/hiding it based on the value of my count variable (`cloneIndex`), but this isn't reliable because the count is shared globally for all rows in the form - not just the specific rows for the day in question.

Comment: I think it would work better to have `style="display: none;"` on the first remove button, then when the row is cloned you can remove that. Or, leave the remove button out then add it when it's cloned.

Comment: @EternalHour Thanks for the suggestion! I've almost got it working, however, when you add a few rows, then delete them all, the `-` icon is visible (a.k.a. I lost the original `style="display: none;"` from the HTML. How would you fix that? Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j856wv7r/

Comment: It's because they all share the same buttons. In order to make it work right you'll have to use the amount of them an always hide it when there's only one.

Comment: In my opinion you need a better HTML structure. The cloned elements are sub-components of that particular day of the week, however, they don't share the same parent container so that makes it really hard to manage them. If they had the same parent, you would easily know how many cloned rows there are by using `.length`.

Comment: On top of that, the cloned form elements are using the same name attribute as the original so when you submit the form there's only going to be one element in the array for that day of the week. When you clone it, you need to add an index to the array so they are all present.

Comment: Could you please add your relevent HTML to your question, it's good that you have an external demo but your "*[mcve]*" code must be in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I feel you need a parent for each day of the week therefore I added `time-interval-parent` to the markup. You also need to reindex your `name` element arrays each time a row is added or removed which required adding a unique class to the inputs and selects so they can be found in the DOM. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eternalhour/ofdrjLah/60/) I put together.

This function takes the select id (day of the week) and uses it for the name attributes. It then modifies the attributes and adds an index.

```
function setIndex(elements) {
    elements.each(function(index, element) {
    var day = $(element).closest(".row").find(".day").attr("id");
    $(element).find("select.from_hours").attr("name", "from_hours[" + day + "][" + index + "]");
    $(element).find("select.to_hours").attr("name", "to_hours[" + day + "][" + index + "]");
  });
}
```

The remove button is initially hidden. I added the functionality in your `clone` function to show it. Then at the end, it passes all the elements to `setIndex` and runs it.

In the `remove` function, it runs `setIndex` again after the element is removed although you don't need to do this if it always removes the last element because the indexes won't change. It also counts the elements and if there is only one, it hides the remove button. Hopefully this gets you close and shows you the different aspects needed for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need JQuery to do this, just use CSS to hide the delete button on the first element. This works by first selecting all the list items with a `.row` class, filters that to the first of those rows, then finds a child with a `.delete` class and hides it.

```css
.row:first-of-type .delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="row">
    first item
    <button class="delete"> - </button>
  </li>

  <li class="row">
    second item
    <button class="delete"> - </button>
  </li>

  <li class="row">
    third item
    <button class="delete"> - </button>
  </li>

  <li class="row">
    fourth item
    <button class="delete"> - </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Interestingly enough, you can use very similar selector syntax in jQuery to perform the same operation (find all rows, get the first row, find the delete button and hide it, otherwise show it).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work in my case (presumably because I'm cloning elements). When I tried it, it causes the delete button to be absent from all subsequent/cloned elements too (https://jsfiddle.net/no6wy97x/).

Comment: @tzazo this is because you've put your `.row` elements inside other elements, so each row is technically the "first" row. You'll have to use a selector on an element that's higher up, above the row. That, or simplify your layout so your rows aren't wrapped.

Comment: If I add a class `.higher-up` to the parent/containing `div` and adjust the CSS to target that instead, I'm still not able to get the desired behavior. I feel like this is close, but I must be missing something simple: https://jsfiddle.net/9hx6pgnm/

Comment: @tzazo As I mentioned, the cloned elements share the same buttons. If you hide the first one this way it is going to hide it for that entire set.